# How smartphones get the right APN Settings?

Tags: linux, modem, gprs, sim-card, apn

I wonder how smartphones get the right APN Settings. Even when i am in a other country.

For example:
It is not possible to dial in in a Netherlands APN when i am in Austria. But everytime my smartphone finds local APN´s it is able to connect to them.
But how if it dont know the right APN settings?

I have a Modem which is connected to a Raspberry Pi and i have tried to put several sim cards from different countries in it which i want to use when i am not in Austria. For every single connection i must give the Dial Program (wvdial) the right APN settings to make it connect.
Isn´t it possible to search for APN´s in reach and automatically connect to them?

Greets

Answer (score 0):

There is something called config-sms witch is a hidden sms the provider sends to your smartphone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your answer to add more detail.